# Is there any way to make the input for SSFIV moves easier?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, street-fighter-iv

I am taking reference of SFXT .. when we select easy input gem (ya our attack goes 10% down) but our input is very simple .. so is there any way like trainer or something else through we can move easier .. my biggest problem is playing with zangief .. i am playing on PC with keyboard it really tough to perform SPD(360 motion).

Comment: I have 4 words for you: macros macros macros macros.

Comment: This is considered cheating. Do not do this if you want to play online.

Comment: when i play online i would use my main character which is GOUKEN or RYU i can easily play both of them but i want to play with ZANGIEF or THAWK offline against computer .. that is why i am asking

Comment: @kotekzot .. how can i use macro in SSF4 .. can u please give me any example or software or trainer??

Comment: You can try http://www.autohotkey.com/ . I used it a couple of times to record dummies to play against in training sessions.

Comment: Find hitbox/keyboard tutorial videos and see how it is done with keys. Some players even find it preferable to do SPD with keys for precision.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to make your input easier, but not like SFxT.

Here are your options:

- Shortcuts: Some commands have shortcuts. For Shoryuken you can input diagonal forward, diagonal forward and punch instead of forward, down, diagonal forward. For SPD you do not need to make a 360 motion, you can only do a 720 motion instead, for example half circle from front to back and diagonal up backwards. An other alternative is to input the cardinal directions forward, down, backward, up and then punch.
- Plinking: "Plinking (sometimes pronounced "P-Linking") stands for "Priority Linking" and is a fundamental technique to getting the most out of your combos. It makes difficult combos much easier to achieve." [see shoryuken.com wiki](http://wiki.shoryuken.com/Super_Street_Fighter_IV/Advanced_Techniques/Plinking)
- Double tapping: "Basically double-tapping helps to make sure that your move comes out properly. It can be applied to doing both special moves and normal moves." [see shoryuken.com forums](http://forums.shoryuken.com/discussion/150669/what-is-double-tapping-arcade-stick)

Aside from that I suggest you get a good controller or a fightstick. I personally prefer fightsticks with Senwa buttons. If you prefer only buttons there is also a controller called Hitbox that is basically a fightstick with only buttons. You can look up some hitbox Street Fighter tutorials like these ones: [see shoryuken.com forums](http://forums.shoryuken.com/discussion/170921/official-hit-box-ssfiv-thread)